# Sending only 1mb of files from folder through web service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

My question is that I want to send pdf files through web service with condition that only 1mb of files are taken from that folder containing many files.

Please help me to resolve this question.I am new to web service.
Ask me again if it not clear.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: which flavor of webservice you are using ?

Comment: apache axis web service on apache tomcat 6.0.20.

Comment: How are you planning to send pdf through webservice? soap attachment or mtom?

Comment: @Pangea:I will send pdf as soap attachment. I don't know about mtom.

Comment: thought so. I suggest you also look at MTOM as it is meant to be a better alternative to SOAP attachments http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363957/Sending-Attachments-with-SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method will return a list of all the files whose total size is <= 1Mb

```
    public List<File> getFilesList(){
    File dirLoc = new File("C:\\Temp");
    List<File> validFilesList = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] fileList;
    final int fileSizeLimit = 1024000; // Bytes
    try {
        // select all the files whose size <= 1Mb
        fileList = dirLoc.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(final File dirLoc, final String fileName) {
                return (new File(dirLoc + "\\" + fileName).length() <= fileSizeLimit);
            }
        });
        long sizeCtr = fileSizeLimit;
        for(File file : fileList){
            if(file.length() <= sizeCtr){
                validFilesList.add(file);
                sizeCtr = sizeCtr - file.length();
                if(sizeCtr <= 0){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        validFilesList = new ArrayList<File>();
    } finally {
        fileList = null;
    }
    return validFilesList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got the solution to this question.                                                     if (outputFolder.listFiles().length != 0) {
   trackFile = outputFolder.listFiles().length;
   files = trackFile;
  }

  while (size <= 1048576) {
   size += sendFiles[files].length();
   files++;
   numberOfFiles++;
  }
  Object[] obj = new Object[numberOfFiles];

Answer (score 1):

Well, I dont know if I have understood your requirements correctly and if this would help your problem but you can try this java solution for filtering the files from a directory.
You will get a list of files and then you can use the web-service specific code to send these files

```
File dirLoc = new File("C:\\California");
File[] fileList;
final int fileSize = 1024000;

try {
   fileList = dirLoc.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
       public boolean accept(final File dirLoc, final String fileName) {
           return (new File(dirLoc+"\\"+fileName).length() > fileSize);
        }
       });
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   fileList = null;
}
```

This should work.
If you just require filenames, replace the `File[]` with `String[]` and `.listFiles()` with `list()`
I cannot say much about the performance though. For a small list of files it should work pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it just give me the file having size more than 1 mb.Mainly I want to collect files from folder whose size totally becomes 1 mb i.e I have let say 12 files in folder,from that I have retreive total of 1mb of files(whether they are 1file or 2file) to send to web service.Hope it clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want but you can pick the files and check their size by :

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("myfile.txt");
file.length();
```

`File.length()`[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)

Send files whose size is 1 Mb.

Comment: Hi Deepak I don't want to calculate the size of each files from folder.But only want to get 1mb of files from that particular folder.I hope that clear your doubt.